# google app script - get image to work on =IMAGE (url)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am not able to display an image (stored in my google drive) to my spreadsheet using Google Apps Script.

Here's what I did so far:

```
=IMAGE(\"" + file.getDownloadUrl() + "\")
=IMAGE(\"" + file.getUrl() + "\")
=IMAGE(\"" + file.getUrl() + "\")
```

And also this:

```
=IMAGE(\"https://googledrive.com/host/[file id here]" + file.getId() + "\")
```

^ If you copy paste the `https://googledrive.com/host/[file id here]` though, on the browser, a new link is created and the image is displayed.  Somehow it's not happening when put as `IMAGE()` formula on spreadsheet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this format for the URL

```
"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id ="+file.getId()
```

practical example on [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X3EnT6PJN0aochHzBNcLYzyHP78-XT9yOnnpQbQ4If0/edit#gid=0) (see end of document)

Comment: I tried that and it still won't appear on the spreadsheet, but upon navigating to the link, it's appearing: 
=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B8-e4RngUsCGLUo2TVVCSFNpV28")
I looked at your spreadsheet, and tried to copy your formula for cells with images and it works on my spreadsheet as well:
=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B3qSFd3iikE3TUFFLWJiN2JiOTVkLTczMDgtNGUyZC1hMjE3LTFkNWY2MzhjNjYyNg")

Would you happen to know why?

Comment: your images must be publicly shared for it to work, yours seem to be private (https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B3qSFd3iikE3TUFFLWJiN2JiOTVkLTczMDgtNGUyZC1hMjE3LTFkNWY2MzhjNjYyNg%22  returns a 404 error even in a browser)

Answer (score 0):

```
var formu = "=IMAGE(\""+ url.toString() +"\")";

sheet.getRange(2,5).setFormula(formu);
```

This worked for me.